# Launching multiple documents in SharePoint via a button or link

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Good Day,
I am hoping someone can help me with my issue. I am working on some enhancements on our SharePoint 2013 site, and one of the things I am looking to do is create a more effective and efficient way in order to launch multiple documents or links via one click or one button. We have a group of analyst, each analyst has a different task or documents they use, and instead of clicking on 20 links, is there a way to create something in code that with one click they can have all the documents launch at once? Appreciate your support and time.